# Adobe Audition - disable XMP metadata files

Tags: adobe-audition, metadata, flac

I can't seem to find a way to disable the creation of XMP files when I edit a .flac file in Adobe Audition 13.0.9.41 (Mac Os).

- If I hit Save as... I can uncheck the option for metadata.
- If I just open a flac file and hit Save, I don't get a Save dialog.

But what I want is to uncheck this globally for Save operations.

Please help me to find a way to disable this .. ;-)

Comment: Why? I'm not seeing the point. Basically you're wanting to treat a multitrack DAW as a single file editor? Normally you'd Export a mix - the sum of the work you've done on all tracks - to a new file, not back to each individual source file.